# Google analytics api. refund товара

Tags: google-analytics

У меня проблема с возвратом через google analytics api. Запрос возвращает ответ 200 без ошибок, но статистика не изменяется (через 24 часа тоже). Я отправил запрос через Hit Builder, но ничего не изменилось.

Запрос [https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXX&cid=95862b2d-fcd7-4334-8f98-c2e46eff75f9&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Refund&ni=1&ti=9619&pa=refund&pr1id=42486&pr1qt=1&hl=ru](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)

Запрос для сохранения заказа (он работает)

[https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=item&tid=UA-XXX&cid=95862b2d-fcd7-4334-8f98-c2e46eff75f9&ti=9619&ic=42486&in=111111&iq=2&ip=3219&iv=222222](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)

Запросы отправляются через post. Get только для удобства и проверки в measurement protocol test tool.

Я не могу понять, где у меня в запросе ошибка, почему он не срабатывает

Comment: Нашел вариант решения с редактированием транзакции https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535738/google-measurement-protocol-update-revenue

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы заработала возврат транзакции, нужно полностью перевести транзакции на расширенную электронную торговлю, то есть добавление транзакции должно быть по другому, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#enhancedecom - через отслеживание расширенной электронной торговли.
Так же сама расширенная торговля должна быть активирована в настройках администратора.
Если добавление транзакции будет через стандартные события transaction или item, то возврат не заработает.